# buidler: address already in use (port 8545)

Tags: hardhat, buidler

I'm trying out the [buidler](https://buidler.dev) suite using [scaffold-eth](https://github.com/austintgriffith/scaffold-eth). I can start up using `yarn start` fine, but when I run `yarn run chain` I get the following error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8545
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as_listen_2] (net.js:1309:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen (net.js:1496:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onLookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:10)
error Command failed with exit code 1
```

Looking at `yarn run chain` in the `package.json` yields that it moves in to the buidler directory and executes `npx buidler node`. A cursory look at the error looks like buidler defaults to port 8545, but that port is indeed already in use on my machine.

The answer should be simple enough - I just need to have buidler launch the dev chain on a different port. I've looked through the [docs](https://buidler.dev/getting-started/), though, and I'm not finding anything.

How do I tell buidler to use a different port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check by running `npx buidler node --help`:

```
$ npx buidler node --help                                                              

Usage: buidler [GLOBAL OPTIONS] node [--hostname <STRING>] [--port <INT>]              

OPTIONS:                                                                               

  --hostname    The host to which to bind to for new connections (default: "localhost")
  --port        The port on which to listen for new connections (default: 8545)        

node: Starts a JSON-RPC server on top of Buidler EVM                                   

For global options help run: buidler help
```

As expected, you can just pass a port using `--port <your-port>`.

Comment: I could've sworn I tried `--port`. Oh well. Thanks!